# How to update the google fonts provided by @font-your-face module?

Tags: theming

I have enabled the [@font-your-face](http://drupal.org/project/fontyourface) module. Then I'm able to use google fonts in my site. Problem is that the list of fonts in the google directory shows more than 500 fonts: [fonts](http://www.google.com/webfonts#ChoosePlace%3aselect) but I just have 300 fonts available.

I need a font called **Imprima**. Is there any way to include this one in the [@font-your-face](http://drupal.org/project/fontyourface) module.

The module is updated to the last version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just updated to a new version, have you gone and re-imported all the fonts you need/want (step 2 below)?  In D6 at least, the following worked here:

1. Install module, enable base and google apis.
2. Go to admin/settings/fontyourface and import google fonts -- 1449 fonts imported
3. Go to admin/build/themes/fontyourface and click browse -- 58 pages of 25 fonts displayed

and sure enough, Imprima is in there when you search.